# viewWithTag does not return object in search

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I have a `tableview` with a custom cell and a search bar. I have tagged the label on the cell because I also have an `imageView` on that cell.

The table displays fine with the label and the image, but in the search, the method viewWithTag does not seem to find the label tagged. As soon as I enter a character in the search bar, the view clears as if no cell with tag 100 was found.
here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        iKl_Stretch *stretchpb  = [self.filteredStretchList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];     
        UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        nameLabel.text = stretchpb.name;
        return cell;

    } else {

        iKl_Stretch *stretchpb  = [self.categoryStretchList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        nameLabel.text = stretchpb.name;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why you search for a subview with tag 100? you're creating the cells using the standard class UITableViewCell, why do you think inside that standard cell there is a subview with tag 100?

Comment: because I assigned a value to that tag which exists by default. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Where you are setting the label tag of each cell ?

Comment: Getting a cell by tag is incorrect if you didn't set it yourself: how do you know that specific cell has tag 100? this could be an implementation detail which is hidden to you. Note that for the standard UITableViewCells Apple offers a standard way to access the main and the detail labels: look at the UITableViewCell documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what was wrong:
The searchDisplayController returns a tableview of its own, so my tagged cells do not exist in this view.
In order to use the custom cell, one must replace the line:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

with:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: I've spent in resolving this problem more than 2 days! Thanks you!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the label is a subview of the cell's `contentView`. Try

```
UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
```

Also, check if your `searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` is properly set up. Sounds like you are getting back no cells.

Comment: Then you might need to check the setup of your search results table.